# Run Twitter Application From My Application To Open A Specific Twitter Account

Tags: android, twitter

I have searched for this today
[Open Twitter app from other app and load some page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901538/open-twitter-app-from-other-app-and-load-some-page)
the code is from that post

```
try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is a tweet");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<?> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            int len =  activityList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
                if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
                    final ActivityInfo activity=app.activityInfo;
                    final ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    intent.setComponent(name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }
      }
        catch(final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("twitter", "no twitter native",e );
        }
```

and its working perfect.

My question is if I can insert something at this code to open a specific Twitter account, for example to open the Twitter account from my website.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); // Create an instance of WebView and set it to the layout component created with id webview in main.xml
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX"); // Specify the URL to load when the application starts
        //myWebView.loadUrl("file://sdcard/"); // Specify a local file to load when the application starts. Will only load file types WebView supports
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewKeep());
        myWebView.setInitialScale(1); // Set the initial zoom scale
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // Initialize zoom controls for your WebView component
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); // Initializes double-tap zoom control
        myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("blablabla");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to open Twitter stream of particular user in official mobile Twitter application?

It's likely possible, but requires some reverse-engineering, as the mobile app doesn't have official integration points defined:

- Get APK of official twitter app on your PC. You can use, for example, app backup tool  in [ASTRO file manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result) to package app into .apk, then copy the APK from SD card to PC
- Decode APK file with [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)
- Looking at decoded AndroidManifest.xml file will give you idea which activity you want to start
- Looking at .smali files will tell you what intent extra arguments is used for passing account name to activity

Similar thing can be done for other Twitter clients like Seesmic, TweetDeck etc.
But this approach is hacky and brittle!

- It relies on official twitter app being installed on the device
- The inner workings of official app can and will change between versions, and the changes will break your code

Here are two alternatives:

- Direct users to twitter's mobile website, simply open mobile browser at, say, "http://mobile.twitter.com/cocacola"
- If you want good control over how the tweet stream looks, load tweets in JSON format from your activity, and display them yourself. This way, you get total control of how they look, but you don't get "reply", "retweet" etc. features on each tweet for free as with mobile website approach

Comment: I have worked the first alternative you have write(before doing the post) and its fine but I have found the code above after.May be I'll get deep into it later but for the time being I am looking for a simple solution. Thanks

Comment: I have solve it by working in another way, open my twitter acoount with webview, you will only have to add at the end of webview this, "myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("blablabla");".