# What is the proper way to launch a twitter profile from iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

Let's say I want the user to be able to view my Twitter account feed via a button in my app's credits view.

What's the proper way to do this?

I can load the URL easily enough to twitter.com but what if the user doesn't use the web version of twitter but the Twitter app or Tweetbot, etc.?

I failed to find anything obvious about a `twitter://` protocol.

Thank you!

Comment: The `twitter://` protocol is meant for the Twitter iOS app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a Twitter tweet by native Twitter app on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424275/open-a-twitter-tweet-by-native-twitter-app-on-ios)

Comment: Indeed a dupe -- I didn't see that one. Thanks!