# How do I do an FB share using a custom url scheme on an iPad?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

From my hybrid app on iPad, I want to share certain URLs through FB & Twitter whenever a user taps on a corresponding button. Here is what I did for twitter (which worked):

```
shareStyleOnTwitter : function(styleId, title) {
    var httpUrl = 'twitter://post?message=';
    var url = 'www.mywebsite.com/'+styleId;
    var params = 'Check out '+title+' on #mywebsite '+url;
    window.location = httpUrl+encodeURIComponent(params);
}
```

This opens a Twitter app with a post dialog window with a message in it. The user just has to tap on the 'tweet' button to post.

Hhere is the function I use for FB (which doesn't work) :

```
shareStyleOnFB : function(styleId, title, imageUrl){
    var httpUrl = 'fb://publish/profile/#me?text=';
    var params = 'www.mywebsite.com/'+styleId;
    console.log(httpUrl+encodeURIComponent(params));
    window.location = httpUrl+encodeURIComponent(params);
},
```

This opens up a FB app with my feed, but no sharing/post/status window with message.

I have taken these ideas from these threads:

[What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Facebook iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707722/what-are-all-the-custom-url-schemes-supported-by-the-facebook-iphone-app/5707825#5707825)

[How can I open a Twitter tweet using the native Twitter app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424275/how-can-i-open-a-twitter-tweet-using-the-native-twitter-app-on-ios)

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with the FB URL scheme?

Comment: my comment in not related to your answer, but I want to ask you is there any way by which we can redirect back to our website after posting message on twitter, currently It stays on twitter app after posting message, is there any way ??

Comment: @ThinkFloyd Do you have discovered how to archieve this?

Comment: No I could not discover how to do this so I used PhoneGap's InAppBrowser plugin to open FB sharing page. It doesn't look that good but it works.