# Twitter call by NSURL

Tags: ios, twitter

I search the different URL which can be used to call Twitter App on iOS
The exact reason is I make a app to send a tweet automatically, i.e when I am back home.
Thank you for answering ... i don't know where to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10424346/3371026

I think it could really help you. All twitter's URLs to use in iOS

Comment: god *.* you did my day