# share tweet with native twitter app from my ios app objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

How to share an tweet with image with the iPhone native twitter app? I have done it using `SLComposeViewController` but I want to perform a tweet with the native twitter app so any help!

Comment: try to use UIActivityViewController

Comment: i want it to open it from twitter native app installed in device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open a Twitter tweet using the native Twitter app on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424275/how-can-i-open-a-twitter-tweet-using-the-native-twitter-app-on-ios)