# Linking in react native can open just one app

Tags: react-native

**UPDATE 1**
I removed `return` from code and now links work on IOS.
But on android I can't open any app. Any idea?

I am trying to open different apps from my app.

```
return Linking.openURL(“twitter://“);
return Linking.openURL(“instagram://“);
```

But it doesn’t work. I configured IOS by documentation. On android doesn’t work too. While...

```
return Linking.openURL(“tripadvisor://“);
```

Work just fine.
Any idea why I can’t open other apps.
This is code that I am using (open app if installed or open store with it but sometimes even store doesn't open) what I did wrong:

```
let appUrl = "instagram://";
Linking.canOpenURL(appUrl).then(supported => {
            if (!supported) {
              Alert.alert("",
                "",
                [
                  {text: "go to store", onPress: this.openStorePress},
                  {text: "cancel", onPress: () => { }, style: 'cancel'},
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
              );
            } else {
              return Linking.openURL(appUrl);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
```

Comment: When you use `return` it also breaks out of particular function you are currently running. So in your upper example it would only trigger first one. I do not see myself any point using return with `Linking.openURL` -method so maybe just leave it out of your code.

Comment: Please prepare a reproduction repository. In your specific issue, anybody can help you just when seeing your sample codes. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue is related to the content of the url, `twitter://` means nothing for the Android Twitter app, so it will not open.

For example, the following code should work:

```
   Linking.openURL('twitter://timeline')
```

or

```
    Linking.openURL('instagram://user?username=apple')
```

You have to find the rights url schemes (documentations are not very clear about it) that may be different between iOS and Android.

- Twitter: [How can I open a Twitter tweet using the native Twitter app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424275/how-can-i-open-a-twitter-tweet-using-the-native-twitter-app-on-ios)
- Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/ (all do not work on Android)
- misc: https://pureoxygenlabs.com/10-app-url-schemes-for-marketers/

Comment: @1110 do not hesitate to ask me for help to find the urls you need

Comment: Hey any idea on how to use this 'instagram://library?AssetPath=${uri}' on Android? On iphone it works fine

Answer (score 9):

You have to find the rights URL schemes. Have look at my code

Instagram

```
Linking.openURL('instagram://user?username=apple')
  .catch(() => {
    Linking.openURL('https://www.instagram.com/apple');
  })
```

Twitter

```
Linking.openURL('twitter://user?screen_name=apple')
  .catch(() => {
    Linking.openURL('https://www.twitter.com/apple');
  })
```

Facebook

```
Linking.openURL('fb://page/PAGE_ID');
Linking.openURL('http://instagram.com/_u/USER_NAME');
Linking.openURL('http://instagram.com/_p/PICTURE');
```

Comment: could you please tell the scheme for facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks pretty solid, here's an example of how I open twitter in my app.

```
const twitterUrlScheme = `twitter://user?screen_name=${twitterUsername}`;

Linking.canOpenURL(twitterUrlScheme)
    .then((supported) =>
        Linking.openURL(
            supported
                ? twitterUrlScheme
                : `https://www.twitter.com/${twitterUsername}`
            )
        )
        .catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

I think perhaps your issue might be the `return Linking.openUrl`, I'm not sure you need the return in that statement. Does it work if you remove the return? Otherwise, it might help to move your `Alert` outside of the then-block from canOpenUrl.

Comment: I get false for supported if I use url “twitter://“ or “instagram://“ (android & ios) can you try those urls in your code please?

Comment: Using the url "twitter://" works for me on initial tests on my iOS device. Curious it doesn't work on yours... did you try removing that return statement?

Comment: Yes I removed return statement but it works on IOS now but on android don't.
Does it work on your android device?
If I use "fb://" on IOS facebook is opened but on android nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have used only url and it's working both iOS and android

```
Linking.openURL('https://www.facebook.com/');
```

Comment: Urls are fine I want to open app if it’s on phone. And it is just nothing happen

Comment: Just put link of app, if app is there it will open by self... btw that worked to me!

Comment: By link of the app you mean like “twitter://“?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't completed the `"` fot twitter and instagram, I don't know whether you made the same mistake in app too, if yes, fixing that might solve it.

Comment: No, it’s typo I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a package like:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share

You can try to use only some of it's functions or look into the native code from there and create some bridge functions in the native code and then export them to be used in JS code.

Note: you will have to use real devices for the tests.

Comment: I have that already. This is something else :-/ On android doesn’t work too.