# (React Native) How to share a message to a particular person on LinkedIn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, linkedin-api

I'm working on a react-native app in which I need to share a message with a particular person/friend/connection on **LinkedIn**.

I tried [react-native's Share component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share) but when I select the **LinkedIn** app to share my message, it just post the message to my profile wall (and not sending it to a particular connection).

Other apps like **Facebook Messenger** for example, when I select `Share with Messenger` it allows me to send the share message to the user(s) I select.

Answer (score 3):

For me you have 3 possibilities:

- To find the right Linkedin App callback url (ex: `linkedin://profile?id=[id]`), my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795246/linking-in-react-native-can-open-just-one-app/52906707#52906707) should help you.
- To look if using the [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) dependency can help you.
- To implement and use a [Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) with the [Linkedin SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk#).